# How do I list only some controllers in an index.gsp of an grails application?

Tags: list, grails, controller, view

index.gsp:

```
    <g:each var="c" in="${grailsApplication.controllerClasses.sort { it.fullName } }">
            <li class="controller"><g:link controller="${c.logicalPropertyName}">${c.fullName}</g:link></li>
    </g:each>
```

This creates a list of all existing controllers. What I need is list of only a few, specific controllers. Is there a way to accomplish that?

For example: my application has 17 controllers, all of them are displayed. I want just 5 to be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a static variable to your controller to determine if the controller should appear in your gsp.

In Controller:

```
static Boolean linkMe = true
```

In GSP:

```
<g:each var="c" in="${grailsApplication.controllerClasses.sort { it.fullName } }">
    <g:if test="${c.getStaticPropertyValue('linkMe', Boolean)}">
        <li class="controller">
            <g:link controller="${c.logicalPropertyName}">${c.fullName}</g:link>
        </li>
    </g:if>
</g:each>
```

Answer (score 1):

If (for example) you only want `UserController` and `LoginController` to be displayed

```
<g:each var="c" in="${[UserController, LoginController]}">            
  <li class="controller">
    <g:link controller="${c.logicalPropertyName}">${c.fullName}</g:link>
  </li>
</g:each>
```

Remember to import the classes for these controllers into the GSP.